# Google App Maker form answer based on previous selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

So the problem I am having is with Google App Maker. I have two SQL databases.. One with employee information and one with recruiters. Each recruiter has a name a percentage and each employee have a recruiter and percentage set to them. So when setting up a new employee I set a recruiter however I cannot automatically set the percentage of the employee based on the recruiter. So I have a form where I select the recruiter and I want to from this also automatically pick the percentage.

There isn't much "coding" to App Maker so I wasn't sure if Stackoverflow would be the best place to come but I thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting, that you actually have one database with two tables I will say that it would better to have relation between `Employee` and `Recruiter` tables. In that case you'll be able to access percentage through the relation and it will be always in sync if updated:

`var percentage = employee.Recruiter.Percentage;`

If you need to create kind of *snapshot* of recruiter's percentage in employee's record, then you can go with `onBeforeCreate` event of the `Employee` model:

`record.Percentage = record.Recruiter.Percentage;`